# Utilizar proxy no nodejs para acessar apis externas

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, proxy

Eu tenho um serviço no NodeJS que faz um fetch para acessar uma api externa:

```
const express = require('express');
const middlewares = require('./middlewares/middlewares');
const routes = require('./routes');
const raven = require('raven');
const config = require('./config');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const winston = require('winston');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console()
    ],
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.colorize(),
        winston.format.json()
    )
});

if (config.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL !== undefined) {
    mongoose.connect(config.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true });

    const app = express();

    middlewares(app);

    app.use('/', routes);
    fetch('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/giuliana-bezerra/demo/comments').then(console.log);

    const startServer = (port = 7755) => {
        const server = app.listen(port, function () {
            raven.config(config.LOG_SENTRY_DSN).install();

            logger.info(`server.settingsservice.initilization.running.${server.address().port}`);
        });
    };

    module.exports = startServer;
} else {
    logger.error(`server.settingsservice.initilization.database.notFound`);
    process.exit(0);
}
```

O problema é que eu uso um proxy coorporativo, e por isso, o fetch fica esperando indefinidamente.

Como eu faço para configurar, de preferência globalmente, o meu proxy para ser usado nas chamadas a apis externas dentro do nodejs? Eu já pesquisei bastante, mas as soluções oferecidas são de configuração de proxy para o próprio serviço node, e não para as chamadas a apis pelo serviço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o módulo [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) para realizar a requisição em conjunto com o módulo [`https-proxy-agent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-proxy-agent) para definir o `proxy`. Para usar em qualquer local da aplicação, crie um módulo dentro da sua aplicação. No meu exemplo chamarei de `requisitar`:

```
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

const requisitar = async (url, options = {}) => {
  const httpsAgent = process.env.PROXY_HOST ? new HttpsProxyAgent(`http://${process.env.PROXY_HOST}:${process.env.PROXY_PORT}`) : null;
  const { data } = await axios.request({ url, httpsAgent, ...options });

  return data;
};

module.exports = requisitar;
```

Dessa forma você pode adicionar as informações de `proxy` nas variáveis de ambiente e utilizará nas chamadas da seguinte forma:

```
const requisitar = require('./requisitar');

// ...

requisitar('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/giuliana-bezerra/demo/comments').then(console.log);
```

Comment: Muito bom! Funciona para uma chamada dentro do meu serviço. Mas e para as chamadas feitas em bibliotecas que eu uso no meu serviço? (e.g. multer-storage-cloudinary). Eu não poderia modificar o código das libs para usar esse módulo. Não existe uma forma global de configurar isso para o nodejs?

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra pior que nesse caso não funciona. Eu olharia na documentação das bibliotecas, mas acabei de checar e nessa que você usou de exemplo não tem nenhuma menção a `proxy`

Comment: Entendi, obrigada pela ajuda. Vou marcar tua resposta aí, pois responde para o exemplo que eu coloquei na pergunta.